# Where can I get AndroidViewClient version >= 5.3.1?

Tags: androidviewclient

In  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23075511/avc-unable-to-find-view-by-id-even-if-parameter-forceviewserveruse-is-true/23118053#23118053)  topic I see @dtmilano talking about AndroidViewClient >= 5.3.1 but I see the latest current AVC version is 5.1.1.
Where can I get AVC >= 5.3.1 ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The latest version is **5.4.4**. It's in the source code and you can get the package using

```
$ sudo easy_install --upgrade androidviewclient
```

With latests AndroidViewclient versions the ZIP file distribution can be obtained by pressing the "**[Download ZIP](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/archive/master.zip)**" button on the bottom right of the page.

Comment: Thank you @dtmilano for this quick answer but, I'm sorry, I couldn't find version 5.4.4 to download using Google & I can't use $sudo easy_install since I'm working in Windows environment